# C - Arrays/Struct discussion

Tags: c

I have to organize a struct or an array of some people's first name, last name, and age then organize them in alphabetical order writing them from an input file to an output file using the string library.

This is partically for a Lab that I have tomorrow afternoon in which my TA said we might be asked to complete the task I stated above. I'm trying to get opinions or suggestions from individuals whom are much more experienced in C than myself so I'll be more prepared than I was last lab where I didn't so hot.

I'm stuck, any suggestions on where I should start?

Comment: Post your attempt so far, so that we have something to work with.

Comment: If this is homework, please add the [tag:homework] tag.  (And I don't think the [tag:discussion] tag is particularly meaningful.)

Comment: This isn't homework, my previous post a couple of hours ago was. This is partically for a Lab that I have tomorrow afternoon in which my TA said we might be asked to complete the task I stated above. I'm trying to get opinions or suggestions from individuals whom are much more experienced in C than myself. Should I tag this as something different?

Comment: Lab is a completely different thing.

Comment: I understand this, sorry I should have mentioned this previous. I still getting used to this site. Should I have written this in a different format or somewhere else?

Comment: 1. What is the input file like?
2. Do you need to organize them alphabetically by name or all the above?

Comment: The point of the exercise may be leaning to use `qsort` from the standard library. Has anyone, perhaps, mentioned function pointers recently? That would be a strong hint in this direction. You'll find several question already on the site concerning how to use `qsort` and `bsearch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, reading and writing the input and output should be a no brainer (you open the file, read/write and then close it when you're done with it).

The trick is to get those pesky strings sorted. 
The way I look at strnig sorting is an array of arrays sorting. The first array-level is an iteration over all the structs while the second is an iteration over all the letters of a name (note that some names are longer then others)
1. First you sort the first column - all the first letters
2. Then all the sub-columns - within each first letter group you sort the second letter
3. Repeat 1&2 until you run out of letters to sort.

The sorting of an array of letters is the same as sorting an array of byte (AKA chars), and if you're working with an algorithm like bubble sort, working on a sub array is seamless.

Hope this idea helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/) from string.h library, which compares two strings and returns the result. 
You should read every string from input file and keep in memory. You will probably use a list for that, for example linked list. While adding you can organize them in alphabetical order. Here is an example:

1. Take the an element in list.
2. Compare it with new string.
3. Where should it be placed? if it should be before the current element, place it before the current element. If it should be after current element, do the same for next element.

This is a simple algorithm for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part is to implement the comparation of two strings. the strcmp function only tells you whether the strings are identical. You can loop through the char array to do it.

Once this is done, the remaining sorting is simple.

Comment: Not actually, it returns 3 different values. You can check the link above for strcmp.